# Which one of these is the best way to access android fragment views?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How are these methods different from each other when trying to get the view?

First:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    return view;
}
```

Second:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);  }
```

* some say this is used to get activity views but i used it for getting fragment views(which didn't existed in the activity) and it worked fine.

Third:

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `getView()` in `onViewCreated()` when the view is passed directly into that method?

Comment: no, i just didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three methods are good. In the `onCreateView` you create the view (!), it's the really first time you can use what you inflated. Then onViewCreated is called with the view you returned in the `onCreateView`, You can directly use the view given as parameter, it is the same the `getView()` provides. My advice is to initialise your UI variables here

For `onActivityCreated`, it is the best place to modify your UI elements. It is called when fragment creation is complete and when fragment is re-attached. There you can use the variables you initialised before, without having to get the activity just for that purpose.

[image: Android Activity and Fragment lifecycle]